# I posted a wrong answer but solved the issue in comments. What to do now?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, edits, wrong-answers

I did like one of those [gangsters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) and rushed in for a quick answer but without enough sleep, didn't notice the answer is not accurate about that question.

Question owner started a comment chat and I ruled out possible issues and finally solved his problem fast now my answer is accepted and anybody without reading the comments cannot find out what had happened.

I have two options:

1. Ask him to delete the whole question.
2. Edit my answer

The latter sounds good but then comments would be confusing to users.

What is proper to do?

Comment: If the comments being confusing bothers you, you can always, you know, *mention* that at the bottom of your answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks. I'm happy living by `Yannis` solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having a correct answer is very important, comments are not.

You should edit your answer and then flag it for moderation attention and ask for the comments to be purged. Write something like "I incorporated useful comments in the answer, please purge them now" in the flag message. Or, if you think some of the comments should remain, you can flag those that should go as "obsolete".

Comment: Moderator didn't remove comments! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862008/ui-thread-freezes-during-textbox-invoking

Comment: @Xaqron Doesn't matter, your answer is now correct.

Comment: @Xaqron, it's also fairly normal to find comment threads that are no longer meaningful as they have been incorporated into the answers. It wouldn't confuse most regular users.